# following fifo in redis

Tags: redis, relationships, fifo

I am trying to implement a Following system in Redis, but I am unsure of how to do it, as I need some sort of queue system as well. This is what I was thinking:

user A, B, and C are following user X, so for the user X to check his followers, I was thinking to use lists like this:

```
X [A, B, C]
```

Do you think this would be a viable solution?

If this would be, I still have the 'queue' problem, say one person can only follow one, if user A chooses to follow user Y, the item 'A' should be removed from the list X.

This might sound confusing: I can't really explain well, as I'm not native. It is also important to note that loads of these operations will occur per second so, can Redis be the best choice for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand for what you need queues? You can use following structure:

**X:followers**   -  is a set containig followers IDs

**X:follows**     -  is a string containig ID of user this user follows

When X follows Y you just do:

```
srem $(X:follows) X
sadd Y:followers X
set X:follows Y
```

Comment: I need the queue so that a certain user cannot follow more than, say, 5 people. when the user follows someone else, the first person who followed, gets un-followed.

Comment: Ok, then ofcourse you can use list with *rpush* for push item in tail and *lpop* for removing one item from head, *llen* to get list length, or jusr *ltrim* to trim list to nessesary length.

Comment: yea, the problem I was thinking about is regarding performance. because in this way, everytime I am following someone else, I need to go to another list and remove myself from there, could that lead to slowliness?

Comment: No, because Redis is very smart